# Ansible: How to loop a command and ignore the return code?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to loop a command and wait for a certain phrase in stdout, but the task will prematurely fail because the command will return "1" if it can't connect. How can I make it ignore the return code?

```
- name: Wait for Fabric Creation to complete
  action: shell /usr/local/jboss/jboss-fuse/bin/client container-list
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("success")
  retries: 20
  delay: 10
```

Comment: the return code is coming on stdout or stderr ? Can you tell the content of result when it does not connect ?

Comment: @Shasha99 I'm not sure what you were asking about. The [return code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) has nothing to do with either stdout nor stderr.

Comment: Ohh.. so you are talking about result.rc . I had some different thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a problem with the command failing (although the task result will be based on the return code of the shell script - this can be altered with `failed_when`).

The real problem is in the following condition itself:

```
until: result.stdout.find("success")
```

`find` returns `-1` value if no match is found, so a boolean check actually passes when there is no `success` string in the stdout. The condition in `until` is thus met on the first run.

---

You need to change the condition to:

```
- name: Wait for Fabric Creation to complete
  action: shell /usr/local/jboss/jboss-fuse/bin/client container-list
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("success") != -1
  retries: 20
  delay: 10
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!